# Apply style to footer on event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the css code:

```
.footer {
  font-family: "lato", sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: right;
  background: #eee;
  color: #0D47A1;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: all 500ms;
}

.footer.scrolled {
  transform: height(100px);
}
```

and I want to make the footer in an html page to disappear when the user scrolls down. I tried to manage it with Javascript, including into my html page the script:

```
function hideFooter() {
                if(window.pageYOffset > 10) {
                    .footer.addStyleName("scrolled");
                } else {
                    .footer.removeStyleName("scrolled");
                }
        }
```

and

```
<body onload="onload()" onscroll="hideFooter()">
```

to make the function activate on scroll. It works if I make an alert appear but it doesn't work for applying the style to the footer and I can't figure why.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+hide+footer+scroll+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: If you want to add or remove a class to an element you should use `classList` + `add` or `remove`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use proper js functions classList.add and classList.remove.

```
function hideFooter() {
    const footer  = document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[0];
    if(window.pageYOffset > 10) {
        footer.classList.add("scrolled");
    } else {
        footer.classList.remove("scrolled");
    }
}
```

Besides, please have a look at the link below to see the issue & solution visually: TestWise Replay | StackOverFlow QA - [Apply style to footer on event in Javascript](https://dashboard.testwise.io/replays/CTmBIrgPdHM)

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked flawlessly!